# Swift - How to force a UISearchBar to search when view loads?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to have a UISearchBar to automatically search for a String and update a UITableViewController. The SearchBar works normally if I type the word myself, but not if the word is already in the bar when the controller loads.

I have found a few questions about this but most of them are quite old or don't work for me. This is what the code looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    
    initSearchController() // this functions generates the searchbar

    loadData() // this function just loads the TableView

}
```

I belive this part is needed for the searchBar to be already active.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {  // must call from main thread
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

This is how I set up the searchBar

```
func initSearchController() {
    
    searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    searchController.isActive = true
    
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
    searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    
}
```

I have tried adding searchController.searchBar.text = "Whatever word". But the TableView doesn't update the results, although the String is there.

Could you please help me make the controller update its results using a previously set String?. I am sorry if something is too obvious or basic, I am new in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can be called on its own by a delegate function that doesn't want to be called on load?

Comment: @neskafesha Hi! could you give me an example? I am not sure what you mean. Thank you

Comment: Hi! updateSearchResults this function called if searchBar becomeFirstResponder or set text. If this function not called in load your viewController, call this function after this -> searchController.searchBar.text = "Whatever word". In updateSearchResults should be getting the right data for the tableView and reloading it (reloadData())